# Polynomial Linked List Adding of Coefficients

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, linked-list

so I'm having trouble getting my code to add the coefficient values when I'm inserting into my linked list and sorted with the highest exponent coming first. For example this is my output:

```
(x^6) + (5x^6) + (3x^2) + (6x^2) + (-1) [end of polynomial] 
(2x^7) + (5x^7) + (2x^5) + (4x^2) +  [end of polynomial]
```

where as they SHOULD be:

```
(6x^6) + (9x^2) + (-1)
(7x^7) + (5x^7) + (2x^5) + (4x^2)
```

here's my code I use to find the spot to insert, and the list insert functions.

```
Node* findSpot (int coefficient, int exponent)
{
    //Node *Spot = new Node (coefficient, exponent);
    Node *spot = listHead;
    while(spot->next != NULL && spot->next->exponent > exponent)
    {

        spot = spot->next;
    }

    /*if (spot->exponent == exponent)
    {
        return spot;
    }*/

  return spot;  
}

//Function to insert into the linked list
void listInsert(int coefficient, int exponent)
{
    Node *spot = findSpot (coefficient, exponent);

    /*if(spot->exponent == exponent)
    {
        int temp;
        temp = spot->coefficient + coefficient;
        //Node *newNode = new Node (temp, exponent);
        spot->coefficient = spot->coefficient + coefficient;
        //Node * newNode = new Node (temp, exponent);
        //newNode->next = spot->next;
        //spot->next = newNode->next;
        //spot = newNode;
    }*/

        Node* newNode = new Node(coefficient, exponent);
        newNode->next = spot->next;
        spot->next = newNode;
}
```

I'm not sure how to change it so that it replaces a node. If I change the pointers, I might have to make a previous pointer for the node as well and that seems to be really annoying. I commented out a bunch of things in the listInsert function that I tried to do if the exponents were the same so that the coefficients could be added, but none of them seemed to work with the current implementation.

Comment: You don't handle the case where there already exists a node with the same exponent, and you just need to add up coefficients. Also known as "combining like terms".

Comment: I'm assuming that would require me to change my while loop. I tried adding if statements for when the exponents are equal but the traversing of the list never seemed to properly work.

Though I did try to do the combining with the commented out if statement in my list insert, but it didn't work.

Comment: `findSpot` does find the right spot - the first node with equal or smaller exponent. `listInsert` should then distinguish between these two cases, and either insert the new node or combine with existing node.

Comment: You look like you are mixing a linked list implementation with logic on how this list is constructed.  Stop that.  Use `std` containers, and failing that wite a container separately from the population of container code.  Polynomial logic should not be mixed in with `new`s and pointer gymnastics, it is pointlessly complicated.

Comment: Just use a `std::set` and I think you would be happy.